# stack panel and scene auto-resize

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, resize, stackpanel

In a javafx application, I have my stage which contains an unique StackPanel.
In this StackPanel, I add the Panel I want to display (depending on what the user want).

Loading the StackPanel view :

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
stackLayout = (StackPane) loader.load();
Scene scene = new Scene(stackLayout);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

Adding a view to this StackPanel :

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/MapGame.fxml"));
AnchorPane map = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
stackLayout.getChildren().clear();
stackLayout.getChildren().add(map);
```

What I want is to automatically resize my StackPane and Stage depending on the size of the child of my StackPane...
For example, my StackPane is 600x400, and the AnchorPane is 800x600, but when the Application is shown, the size is 600x400... Anybody ?

Comment: The behavior you wish (automatic sizing of a stage to the preferred size of it's scene contents *when the scene is initially displayed*), will occur by default unless additional constraints are set in java code or FXML.  To get assistance, you need to supply an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which is minimal code that somebody could copy and paste to compile and run (without change) to replicate your issue.  For brevity, you may wish to supply your mcve using only java code and not using FXML at all, but if you use FXML you should supply it.

Answer (score 0):

After these lines

```
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

add the following:

```
stage.sizeToScene();
```

**Edit:** Try using this order in your code:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
stackLayout = (StackPane) loader.load();

loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/MapGame.fxml"));
AnchorPane map = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

stackLayout.getChildren().clear();
stackLayout.getChildren().add(map);

Scene scene = new Scene(stackLayout);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
stage.sizeToScene();
```

Comment: I already tried, but this doesn't change. My frame is still the size of the StackPanel.

Comment: If you add a child to your stackpane after calling `stage.sizeToScene()`, it won't work. Try calling `stage.sizeToScene()` at the very end.

Comment: I also tried to do it after the `stackLayout.getChildren().add(map);` , but there's no change.

Comment: Sorry but once again, no changes. I think my stage is correctly sized according to the StackPanel BUT the StackPanel doesn't resize to its children...